# Multiple answers to the same question

Tags: discussion

Is it acceptable to answer a question multiple times, or should that be discouraged?

When I have multiple answers to a question, I tend to just edit my answer and provide them (or sometimes I'll delete an answer and then later provide a new one if the first one misunderstood the question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I somewhat prefer one person, one answer, and don't like the "everyone post one answer for each package" type questions.  But it's not an abuse of the system to post multiple answers.  An old question, from before the days of meta.so, [Is it OK to post multiple answers to a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60445/is-it-ok-to-post-multiple-answers-to-a-question), received a nice answer from Shog:

> #### On questions with multiple specific but distinct answers:
>
> If both answers are valid, then sure, although I would probably edit my original answer to provide both (along with pros / cons / my preference) rather than posting a new answer.
>
> If you suspect one answer might be preferable to the other, but don't really have a good feel for why or how, then by all means post them separately - the voting and comment system are designed for it.
>
> #### On questions with multiple broad but distinct answers:
>
> These tend to be discussion questions. Write an essay, touch on both answers, detail your thought process. The exception would be "poll" questions, in which each answer should be a single concept (and, marked Community Wiki).

Some people are concerned that multiple answers to non-wiki questions can be a form of gaming, because a single person can award more upvotes.  My impression is that doing this reduces total upvotes, compared to making the effort to craft a single comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, one should not give multiple answers.

However, I think multiple answers are appropriate (and encouraged) in big-list CW questions. Often it is best to give one "thing" (one tool, one package, etc.) per answer, so that people can rank them by voting up/down.