# Posting a question very close to an already solved one

Tags: discussion

I posted the question entitled [Aligning TikZ trees with other nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16491) when in fact it should have been "Aligning one TikZ tree with other nodes". The question was answered and I accepted the answer as it solved the question (for one single tree). But now I ask myself how to align *multiple* TikZ trees and not just one.

My question is: should I post a new question entitled "Aligning multiple TikZ trees with other nodes" with a reference to the old one or should I edit the previous post and toggle it as unsolved, though the answer given was ok for that specific question ? Both ways make me uncomfortable. I guess the first one is more acceptable than the other one.

I already read [Multiple answers to the same question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/556/4735) but it doesn't solve my problem as the question is not exactly the same.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Post a new question, referencing the old one. And explain why the old solution doesn't work in the new situation.

Comment: I agree. And next time pause a little while to reread your question to check that it is really the question that you intended to ask, before submitting it :-)